# How to set mimum font size in Google chrome(Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, fonts

I am using Google chrome(**55.0.2883.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)**) on **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** and having trouble setting the minimum font size.

Installed [Advanced font chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-font-settings/caclkomlalccbpcdllchkeecicepbmbm?hl=en) and set the minimum font size setting as 16px as in the below screenshot:

[image]

But when I browse any sites the minimum font size setting is not applied. Here is the screenshot of the font size displayed on slickdeals.net(measured using **whatfont chrome extension**.)

[image]

What am I missing here?

**NOTE:** Not sure if I should post this on askubuntu.com but somehow I felt, this qualifies for superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) Chrome extension
2. Open Tampermonkey settings
3. Click the new script icon (before "Installed scripts" tab)
4. In "Update URL", put: *
5. In script input, put the following (replace actual function block). Be sure to replace 20px with whatever you wish:

   ```
   (function() {
       'use strict';
       $('*').css('fontSize', function(i, fs){
           if(parseInt(fs, 10) < 20 ) return this.style.fontSize = "20px";
       });
   })();
   ```
6. CTRL + S

Comment: I did not think of this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest ["StyleBot" chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha)

To set the font size on all websites:

1. Open the Stylebot settings
2. Select "Styles" in the left panel
3. Click "Edit Global Stylesheet" button
4. Write a font size rule such as:

   ```
   * {
       font-size: 20px;
   }
   ```
5. Click save

Comment: This worked excellent! I will settle with this for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from Advanced Font Settings description page:

> Chrome will use the font settings controlled by this extension when BOTH of the following are true:
>   1) The web page has declared the language of the content (e.g., by using the HTML lang attribute); and
>   2) The web page has not specified a font to use.

Comment: How do I change default font size?

Comment: You mean for a web site that has CSS style sheets? Try the Stylish plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en-US Or, StyleBot too. I see you've already accepted that answer. So...